# Passing data returned from SOAP service to custom object array

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I want to pass data returned from a soap / xml service to my custom object array. I am not sure if the data I converted to string below is an xml, json or string?

[image]

How can I pass the data of cityID and cityName here to my custom city array with cityID and cityName members?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like some JSON embedded in XML:) Just get rid of XML stuff and the rest could be simply decoded via [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder).

Answer (score 0):

The response data was not JSON but JSON embedded in XML, so I first converted the response data to text and removed the HTML tags with below String extension, then I converted that text to json.

```
extension String{
var removeHTMLTags : String{
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
}
```